# Copy from Closed Workbook based on criteria and paste into master file

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on a VBA that will copy data from a closed workbook based on a certain criteria and paste into the next available row in master workbook.  I can copy and paste sheet to sheet with a vba, but I cannot figure out how to do this from workbook to workbook.

I have my master workbook, "Availability Master", with a "Running Data" sheet.  I  have a closed workbook, "Add/Delete", with a "Combined" sheet.  This is the sheet that I need master to look in for rows that start with "Add-Crazy" and copy all the data and paste into Availability Master.

This is what I had for same workbook, but again I need it to look in a closed workbook.

```
Private Sub Copy ()
    a=Worksheets("Combined").Cells(Rows.Count,1)End(xlUp).Row
    For i=2 to a
    If worksheets("Combined").Cells(i,1).Value="Add-Crazy" Then
        Worksheets("Combined").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Running Data").Activate
        b=worksheets("Running Data").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Running Data").Cells(b+1,1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Combined").Activate
    End if
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode=False
    thisworkbook.Worksheets("Combined")
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot do this with a closed workbook - you will need to open it first.